# How to programmatically trigger bootstrap 5 validation on button click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form with validation. If I put a submit button on the form, the validation works perfectly, however my button is hooked to a click event where I would like to perform some other actions, however I don't know how to programmatically trigger the validation.

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-outline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" required />
        <label for="validationCustom01" class="form-label">First name</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Works</button>
    <button id="test" class="btn btn-primary">Click Doesn't</button>
</form>
```

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // validate here

    // do other things if form is valid
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `checkValidity()` [JavaScript function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp). An example:

```
if ($('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
  // Form is valid;
} else {
  // Form is invalid;
}
```

Remember, if you use a jQuery selector for the form, you have to indicate the index (`[0]` in the code above) because `checkValidity()` is a JavaScript function, not a jQuery function.